# Monitoring overlapping regions

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, location

I use region monitoring in ios 6 and 7. It works fine, if regions are not overlapping. But if some regions are overlapping then the app calls delegate method `didEnterRegion` only for one region.

My code:

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
_locationManager.delegate = self;

for (XPLocationModel* locationModel in models) {
 if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(startMonitoringForRegion:)]) {
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:locationModel.region];
} else if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy:)]) {
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:locationModel.region desiredAccuracy:XPGeofenceMaster_DesiredAccuracy];
}
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
   NSLog(@"%s id == %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, region.identifier);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
   NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can use the requestStateForRegion: method to get an update about all of your states, something like this. However, you better be prepared for enter and exit to be called multiple times.

```
- (void)requestStateForAllLocations
{
    for (CLRegion *region in self.locationManager.monitoredRegions) { 
          [self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:region];
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually fires the delegate method : `-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region`